# Image Intervention w/ Laravel Storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the storage facade to store an avatar which works fine, but I want to resize my image like I did in previous versions of Laravel.
How can I go about doing this?
Here is what I have so far (doesn't work)

```
  $path   = $request->file('createcommunityavatar');
  $resize = Image::make($path)->fit(300);
  $store  = Storage::putFile('public/image', $resize);
  $url    = Storage::url($store);
```

Error Message:

```
  Command (hashName) is not available for driver (Gd).
```

Comment: Hi try this  Image::make($path)->resize(300, 300);

Comment: That gave me the same error as before. `Command (hashName) is not available for driver (Gd).`

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @CriticalTheWizard Changing driver to `imagick` didn't help. Now I get `Command (hashName) is not available for driver (Imagick).`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're trying to pass into putFile wrong object. That method expects File object (not Image).

```
$path   = $request->file('createcommunityavatar');

// returns \Intervention\Image\Image - OK
$resize = Image::make($path)->fit(300);

// expects 2nd arg - \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile - ERROR, because Image does not have hashName method
$store  = Storage::putFile('public/image', $resize);

$url    = Storage::url($store);
```

Ok, now when we understand the main reason, let's fix the code

```
// returns Intervention\Image\Image
$resize = Image::make($path)->fit(300)->encode('jpg');

// calculate md5 hash of encoded image
$hash = md5($resize->__toString());

// use hash as a name
$path = "images/{$hash}.jpg";

// save it locally to ~/public/images/{$hash}.jpg
$resize->save(public_path($path));

// $url = "/images/{$hash}.jpg"
$url = "/" . $path;
```

Let's imagine that you want to use Storage facade:

```
// does not work - Storage::putFile('public/image', $resize);

// Storage::put($path, $contents, $visibility = null)
Storage::put('public/image/myUniqueFileNameHere.jpg', $resize->__toString());
```

Comment: Above code is working perfectly fine, with one note: `md5($resize->__toString());` is returning always the same hash for the same file, which might be problematic in some cases.

In my solution I have replaced that with
    
      `$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
      $hash = md5($image->__toString().$now);`

Answer (score 30):

The **put** method works with the Image intervention output.
The **putFile** method accepts either an Illuminate\Http\File or Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instance.

```
$photo = Image::make($request->file('photo'))
  ->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); } )
  ->encode('jpg',80);

Storage::disk('public')->put( 'photo.jpg', $photo);
```

The above code resizes the uploaded file to 400px width while holding the aspect ratio. Then encodes to jpg at 80% quality.
The file is then stored to the public disc.
Note you must provide a filename, not just the directory.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Note that the `encode` call is required, otherwise the output will be corrupted.

Comment: And you may also use it like this: `Storage::disk('public')->put( $request->file('photo')->hashName(), $photo);`

Comment: Really helpful for me

Answer (score 18):

### Using Laravel 5.8

I had a similar issue when trying to **read** an image file with `Image` when this one was **saved** and **loaded** with `Storage`.
Beside all the answers I wasn't sure why it wasn't working.

---

Exception when `Image` was trying to read the file

> Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException : Unable to init from given binary data.

#### Short answer

Adding `->encode()`solved the issue

http://image.intervention.io/api/encode

#### Scenario

Basically I had a test like this

```
Storage::fake();

$photo = factory(Photo::class)->create();    
$file = \Image::make(
    UploadedFile::fake()->image($photo->file_name, 300, 300)
);

Storage::disk($photo->disk)
    ->put(
        $photo->fullPath(),
        $file
    );
```

And in the controller I had something like this

```
return \Image::make(
    Storage::disk($photo->disk)
        ->get(
            $photo->fullPath()
        )
)->response();
```

#### Solution

After investigation I realized that any file created by `Image` and saved by the `Storage` had a size of **0 octets**.
After looking at all the solutions from this post and few hours after, I noticed everyone was using `encode()` but no one did mention it was that. So I tried and it worked.

Investigating a bit more, `Image` does, in fact, **encode** under the hood before saving.
https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L146

So, my solution was to simple doing this

```
$file = \Image::make(
    \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::fake()->image('filename.jpg', 300, 300)
)->encode();

\Storage::put('photos/test.jpg', $file);
```

*testable in **Tinker**, It will create a black image*

Comment: Thats the same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700717/2311074

Comment: It also worked while uploading a base64 decoded image file and store it using storage. Without using encode() function, it wasn't uploaded when I used `Storage::put($file_path, base64_encode($uploadedFile);`. At last using intervention image and encode function, it worked.

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest solution I could find—using the native `Storage` facade—is the following. I can confirm that this works in Laravel 5.7, using `intervention/image` version 2.4.2.

```
$file = $request->file('avatar');
$path = $file->hashName('public/avatars');
$image = Image::make($file)->fit(300);
Storage::put($path, (string) $image->encode());

$url = Storage::url($path);
```

Comment: I recieve the next error using your example (i'm working with xampp, php8 and laravel8) message: "file_put_contents(C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\storage\\app\\public): Failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Answer (score 6):

I do it this way:

1. Resize and save image somewhere (such as in the public folder).
2. Create a new File and pass it to Laravel filesystem functions (such as putFileAs).
3. Delete temporary intervention file

Note: Of course you can modify it according to your needs.

```
$file = $request->file('portfolio_thumb_image');

$image = Image::make($file);

$image->resize(570, 326, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$thumbnail_image_name = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$image->save(public_path('images/'.$thumbnail_image_name));

$saved_image_uri = $image->dirname.'/'.$image->basename;

//Now use laravel filesystem.
$uploaded_thumbnail_image = Storage::putFileAs('public/thumbnails/'.$portfolio_returned->id, new File($saved_image_uri), $thumbnail_image_name);

//Now delete temporary intervention image as we have moved it to Storage folder with Laravel filesystem.
$image->destroy();
unlink($saved_image_uri);
```

Comment: It works just fine. This should be the accepted answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add `use Illuminate\Http\File;` to top of your file for this to work, and read through the documentation section [*Automatic Streaming*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files).

**This assumes you want all jpegs**

```
$path   = $request->file('createcommunityavatar');
$resize = Image::make($path)->fit(300)->encode('jpg');
$filePath = $resize->getRealPath() . '.jpg';
$resize->save($filePath);
$store  = Storage::putFile('public/image', new File($resize));
$url    = Storage::url($store);
```

**This is how I am doing it in my application with comments to help**

```
// Get the file from the request
$requestImage = request()->file('image');

// Get the filepath of the request file (.tmp) and append .jpg
$requestImagePath = $requestImage->getRealPath() . '.jpg';

// Modify the image using intervention
$interventionImage = Image::make($requestImage)->resize(125, 125)->encode('jpg');

// Save the intervention image over the request image
$interventionImage->save($requestImagePath);

// Send the image to file storage
$url = Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File($requestImagePath), 'thumbnail.jpg');

return response()->json(['url' => $url]);
```

Comment: did you mean `$filePath = $resize->getRealPath() . '.jpg';`

Comment: I tried it out on a fresh install of laravel 5.3.*, this works. Did you try it out?

Comment: what kind of new File your are using here? http file or facades file?

Comment: Use the `File` Facade.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it with following way, its simple and without any path confusion :

```
//Get file
$path= $request->file('createcommunityavatar');

// Resize and encode to required type
$img = Image::make($file)->fit(300)->encode('jpg');

//Provide own name
$name = time() . '.jpg';

//Put file with own name
Storage::put($name, $img);

//Move file to your location 
Storage::move($name, 'public/image/' . $name);
```

Comment: `$path = $request->file()` should be `$file = $request->file()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the GD extension for the current php version.

If that doesn't help, try saving the resized image on local disk and using Storage::putFile.

You may delete the file once it has been uploaded to your storage path.

The second parameter to your putFile method is an instance of the Image Intervention class. You need to pass this as the second parameter to the putFile method.

```
$resize->save($absolutePath . 'small/' . $imageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an \Intervention\Image\Image object directly with the Laravel 5 filesystem. What you can do is resize the image from your request, and save it under the same tmp path. Then just store the uploaded (overwritten) file to the filesystem.

Code:

```
$image  = $request->file('createcommunityavatar');
//resize and save under same tmp path
$resize = Image::make($image)->fit(300)->save();
// store in the filesystem with a generated filename
$store  = $image->store('image', 'public');
// get url from storage
$url    = Storage::url($store);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by calling the hashName method on an image instance.

```
    //initially
    $image = Image::make(request('image')->getRealPath());
    $filename = $image->hashName();

    //to fix the error
    $image = Image::make(request('image')->getRealPath());
    $filename = request('image')->hashName();
```