# How do I use Image Intervention with Laravel Storage and digital ocean

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Laravel storage feature to store images on DigitalOcean which works fine but I can't seem to add image intervention because I want to use the orientate feature. This is so that images created through the phone doesn't rotate sideways. How do I add image intervention to my existing code?

```
   if ( $request->hasFile('image')) {
        $extension = $request->file('image')->extension();
        $mimeType = $request->file('image')->getMimeType();
        $path = Storage::disk('do')->putFileAs('public/images', $request->file('image'), time() . '.' . $extension);
        Storage::disk('do')->setVisibility($path, 'public');
        $product->image = $path;
    }
```

So i tried different ways of implementing image intervention haven't had much success but here my updated code. An with that i got a error saying `Command (GetRealPath) is not available for driver (Gd).`

```
$image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('/images/' . $filename);

        $extension = $request->file('image')->extension();
        //$mimeType = $request->file('image')->getMimeType();
        $orientate = Image::make($image)->orientate();
        $path = Storage::disk('do')->putFileAs('public/images', $orientate, $filename);

        Storage::disk('do')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

        $product->image = $path;
```

Comment: Hi there, can you please tell us what you've tried thus far for implementing the image intervention feature? Thanks.

Comment: @1000Nettles hey I updated my question with some code i have been trying out not much success but i am getting a error that say Command (GetRealPath) is not available for driver (Gd).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image Intervention w/ Laravel 5.4 Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025456/image-intervention-w-laravel-5-4-storage)

Comment: I flagged your question as a duplicate as I'm almost 100% positive your answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531889/823549. Good luck!